# Checkboxes in PHP

Tags: php, checkbox

I have HTML

```
<td><input value="on" checked="checked" name="checkbox1[0]" type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input value="on" checked="checked" name="checkbox2[0]" type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input value="on" checked="checked" name="checkbox3[0]" type="checkbox"></td>
```

and function

```
function checkbox_verify($_name) {
    $result = 0;
    if(isset($_REQUEST[$_name])) {
        if($_REQUEST[$_name] == 'on') {
            $result = 1;
        } else {
            $result = 0;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

using:

```
$tmp = checkbox_verify("checkbox[$k]") . " " . checkbox_verify("checkbox2[$k]"). " " . checkbox_verify("checkbox3[$k]");
```

I want to just check checkbox - checked it or not. But everytime result is "0"

Comment: and where you are using this method checkbox_verify() ?

Comment: You can directly use php isset function instead of compare with 'on'

Comment: What is the value of `$_name`?

Comment: Quentin: with value of $_name all okay. its checkbox[0], checkbox[1] and etc

Answer (score 2):

PHP automatically converts `foo[bar]`-style field names into an array. So you will need to check for `$_REQUEST['checkbox1'][0]`. Since a checkbox only has a value if checked the following check is sufficient:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['checkbox1'][0])) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Another option would be renaming your checkboxes to not include brackets. Then you could simply check `$_REQUEST['name-of-the-checkbox']`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `[0]` of the name:

```
<td><input value="on" checked="checked" name="checkbox1" type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input value="on" checked="checked" name="checkbox2" type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input value="on" checked="checked" name="checkbox3" type="checkbox"></td>
```

Then you could check it just with `isset`:

```
function checkbox_verify($_name) {
  return isset($_REQUEST[$_name]);
}
```